# How to allow only numbers in specific cell while editing using Winform

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Control.KeyPress -= new KeyPressEventHandler(polNumDataGridViewTextBoxColumn_KeyPress);
    if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 3) //Desired Column
    {
        TextBox tb = e.Control as TextBox;
        if (tb != null)
        {
            tb.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(polNumDataGridViewTextBoxColumn_KeyPress);
        }
    }
}

private void polNumDataGridViewTextBoxColumn_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the problem with your code?

Comment: It does not work actually I want to validate like only numbers should be allowed no any junk characters @MongZhu

Comment: I copy/paste your code and it works as expected. Something else must be going on. Also, just as an FYI: Preventing the user from “typing” invalid characters is a good idea, however, since the user can “paste” data… you STILL need to validate the data when the user leaves the cell.

Answer (score 1):

The control in the gridview is not a `TextBox`. It is a `DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl`

I made this working test (my control names and column indexes are different):

```cs
private void DataGridView2_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control is DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl tb) {
        tb.KeyPress -= Tb_KeyPress;
        tb.KeyPress += Tb_KeyPress;
    }
}

private void Tb_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView2.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 1 &&
        !char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

But using data binding is usually the better approach and it fixes the problem automatically. I.e. when a cell is bound to numeric property or DateTime property is behaves accordingly.

Comment: I am getting error at tb as the name 'tb' does nor exist in the current context  ) expected

Comment: Did you write `e.Control is DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl tb` with `tb` at the end? Which c# version are you using? The type pattern works starting with c# 7.

Comment: //    if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 4 &&
            //e.Control is DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl ) {

            //        tb.KeyPress -= Tb_KeyPress;
            //        tb.KeyPress += Tb_KeyPress;
            //    }

Comment: I write like this inside the event

Comment: the `tb` is missing after `e.Control is DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl`. Write `tb` between `DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl` and `)`.

Comment: @JohnG. Okay, it seems indeed that the `DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl` is a singleton. I have adapted my code. Thank you for the comment.